# Finding overlap of three polygons using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, overlapping-features

I have three polygon areas showing different land types and I want to create a new layer based on where the three layers overlap each other.

I thought this was a subtraction query but havent been able to achieve this in ArcGIS for Desktop.

Answer (score 5):

In ArcGIS for Desktop, to do this with an Advanced or Standard license, you just need to use the **[Intersect (Analysis)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000p000000)** tool and input the three layers at once.

If you are using Basic then you will need to use the same tool twice - once to intersect the first two layers, and then again to intersect the result with the third layer.

Comment: +1 Or, to avoid extra work, put the three polygons into a single layer and `Union` that layer with itself.